# Interpolation pipe not working for uppercase angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Okay,

I have three values, ParentTitle and childTitle, SiblingTitle. All coming from the Header[] array.

```
 <li *ngFor="let header of headers">
      <div>
        <a> <i class="header-icons" [ngClass]="[header.titleIcon]"></i>
          <span class="menu-parentTitle">{{header.parentTitle | uppercase}}<


 headers: Header[] = [
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
{
  parentTitle: ['Settings'], childTitle: ['General Setup', 'PMS Setup', 'Crewing Setup', 'Purchase Setup', 'Safety Setup',
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    'RA Setup', 'RH Setup', 'Voyage Setup'], siblingTitle: ['Vessel', 'Port', 'Owner', 'Engine Type', 'Vessel Type'],
  titleIcon: 'ft-settings', url: 'home/general-setup'
},
{ parentTitle: ['Data Sync'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-zap', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['PMS'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-layers', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Crewing'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-users', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Purchase'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-shopping-cart', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Safety'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-plus-square', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Document'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-folder', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Forms'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-paperclip', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Risk Analysis'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-shield', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Rest Hours'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-clock', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Voyage'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-compass', url: '' },
{ parentTitle: ['Environment'], childTitle: [], siblingTitle: [], titleIcon: 'ft-droplet', url: '' }
```

];

All of them coming from server rest api, and stored as arrary[] strings. So inside the div tag i use *ngFor loop to show all of the title. That's works fine.

So {{ childTitle | uppercase }} works fine. But {{ parentTitle.title | uppercase }} ---> not working or not showing the text at all.

What could be the issue!.

Comment: You mentioned that all the values are stored as arrays. In that case parentTitle.title will be undefined since this is not object. Hence the uppercase is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access title from an array, it should be,

```
{{ parentTitle[0]?.title | uppercase }}
```

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned its just an array of strings, you can access string directly since you really dont have an object

```
<span class="menu-parentTitle">{{header | uppercase}}<
```

again after i checked your latest JSON , it seems you need

```
li *ngFor="let header of headers">
      <div>
        <a> <i class="header-icons" [ngClass]="[header.titleIcon]"></i>
          <span class="menu-parentTitle">{{header.parentTitle[0] | uppercase}}
```

Comment: would you please take look at the edited question. thanks!

Comment: you should juse use   <span class="menu-parentTitle">{{header | uppercase}}<

Comment: post what you have in headers array

Comment: pls take a look!

Comment: you need to use nested ngFor  check above